# How Adobe AIR program can to index all images on a user's computer?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, air, mxml

What is the fastest way for a Adobe AIR program program to index all images on a users' computer?

Using Open Source ActionScript-3, MXML Libs and classes.

- Fastest - Same pc configuration, different time (seconds)
- To index - get a list of absolute links (like c://bla-bla/file ) and save them into file (index.txt)
- All images (like JPEGs, PNGs)

Comment: why would you want to do this?

Comment: in this particular case - Itunes analog for Photos=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's the fastest, but what comes to mind is using [AIR's Native Process API](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/interacting_with_native_process.html) to make the search through command prompt.

A simple example would be

```
find *.jpg *.jpeg *.png
```

You can then use standardOutput.readUTFBytes. This might be faster then writing the search result to a text file then loading.
After that you can parse the file. You can always have a look at the find options for better results.

Anyway, just a thought...speaking of which,
to quote @quoo:

> why would you want to do this?

Comment: Will find *.jpg *.jpeg *.png work on mac lin and win?
=) I want to create Itunes analog for Images.

Comment: Actually, is not a bad idea. In Windows you could use dir /S: http://www.computerhope.com/dirhlp.htm. The other option seems to be recursively read folders, which is probably quite slow.

Comment: @Ole Jak the find command is on linux/osx as well, but you might be better of using locate instead of find. @Zárate yup! the dir and tree options can be quite

Comment: Ok by now... But pure AS3\MXML way would be cooler (in a way - Native installer will not ever soon be a way for mobile devices, I (my self) Do not know how to install AIR app from Browser (Using Badger) and there will be no default way to run app from browser=( ) but AIR AS3\MXML way probably will be mych slower... Will it be much slower?

Comment: @Ole Jak There is a badge sample that comes with the AIR SDK. Also there is this article on devnet: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/air_badge_install_print.html and gskinner's AIR Badger: http://www.gskinner.com/blog/archives/2008/09/beware_the_air.html. HTH,George